# C# при выводе в консоль ALT + 1 должен выводится смайлик

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

C# при выводе в консоль ALT + 1  должен выводится смайлик, на WIndwos 7 так и есть, но у меня Windows 10   и я не могу вывести смайлик,а мне он нужен для игры.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
Console.WriteLine("\u263A");
```

Коды можно посмотреть с помощью "Таблица символов" и выбрать шрифт `Segoe UI Emoji`

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Да, пожалуйста.